# Excel 'Text to Columns' when there are no spaces

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have about 800 rows of data in a single column. The data in the column looks like this:

```
|Column A                        |  
|195Marriott International127,500|
```

How can I have excel break this out into columns so it looks like as follows:

```
|Column A| |Column B| |Column C|  
|195| |Marriott International| |127,500|
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can because you don't have any delimiters of any kind. Unless there's an unprintable character I can't see. Your only hope would be if the "columns" in your data had fixed widths. If you're guaranteed that ColA and ColC are *always* numbers and ColB is *always* non-numeric, you could do this with a macro.

Comment: Are columns A and C always going to be numeric? Or more precisely, will column A always end with a number, and will column C always start with a number?

Comment: @OldUgly - yes, that is the case here

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

But you do have some patterns that you can use. Note that you have numbers in the first and third column items. Select column A, extract last character with =RIGHT(). You will only need 9 replacements to make (1 - 9), then concatenate the value. Do the same with the first number in the 3rd Column. You will then have delimiting values to use text to column.

====
you can use the Text to Column tool under the data tab on excel.

You can split the contents of one or more cells in a column, and then distribute those contents as individual parts across other cells in adjacent columns. For example, if your worksheet contains a column of full names, you can split that column into separate first name and last name columns.

Comment: It's a bit more difficult than that because of the lack of delimiters. I haven't been able to find a way

Comment: Is the lhs always 3 numbers, never 2 or 4?

Comment: Is the lhs always 3 numbers, never 2 or 4? And the right 3,3? Then left(A1,3) will give the number, mid(A1,4,len(A1)-10) will give the name and right(A1,7) the last but not as a number usable in a calculation. Note that if either number changes length then things stop working...

Answer (score 0):

I see you found a solution from Solar Mike's comment, but here's an alternative.

---

Below is a short piece of VBA that will preprocess the data, inserting a delimiter that will work. I tested it on a limited amount of data, so it may generate errors that need to be corrected.

The VBA ...

```
Option Explicit
Sub MakeDelimiters()
Dim LastRow As Long, iLoop As Long
Dim myDelim As String, myStr As String
Dim theRng As Range, theSht As Worksheet, theCell As Range

    myDelim = ";"

    Set theSht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = theSht.Range("A" & theSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set theRng = theSht.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

    For Each theCell In theRng
        myStr = theCell.Value
        For iLoop = 1 To Len(myStr)
            If IsNumeric(Mid(myStr, iLoop, 1)) And _
               Not IsNumeric(Mid(myStr, iLoop + 1, 1)) And _
               Mid(myStr, iLoop + 1, 1) <> "," Then
                myStr = Left(myStr, iLoop) & myDelim & Right(myStr, Len(myStr) - iLoop)
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Mid(myStr, iLoop + 1, 1)) And _
               Not IsNumeric(Mid(myStr, iLoop, 1)) And _
               Mid(myStr, iLoop, 1) <> "," And _
               Mid(myStr, iLoop, 1) <> myDelim Then
                myStr = Left(myStr, iLoop) & myDelim & Right(myStr, Len(myStr) - iLoop)
            End If
        Next iLoop
        theCell.Value = myStr
    Next theCell

End Sub
```

Converted this ...

[image]

to this ...

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:**

The idea that a future visitor's data would look oversimplified ...

> Is the lhs always 3 numbers, never 2 or 4? And the right 3,3?  -SolarMike

... is laughable.  So I came up with this solution. This answer is predicated on the comments:

> Are columns A and C always going to be numeric? Or more precisely, will column A always end with a number, and will column C always start with a number? – OldUgly
>
> @OldUgly - yes, that is the case here – BigMike

---

To answer your original question about "Text to Columns", I have no idea.  However, this was tagged *excel-formula*, so I gave it a shot and came up with this ...

[image]

... which assumes you really want the data in columns `A-C`.  The two helper **array formulas** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)in `E2` and `F2` respectively are ...

```
=MIN(FIND(0,SUBSTITUTE(D2,CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("65:90"))),0)&0))
=MIN(FIND(0,SUBSTITUTE(D2,CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("48:57"))),0)&0,E2+1))
```

The formulas in `A2`, `B2`, and `C2` respectively are (pretty obvious) ...

```
=LEFT(D2,E2-1)
=MID(D2,E2,F2-E2)
=RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2)-F2)
```

*Ah, good old ASCII tables*

Comment: Shame you did not read my answer in the comments... And, if you do, you will see how to use find() with mid to get the name without using extra columns.